# Is a parametrization $\mathbb{C}^3 \ni (\rho, u, \eta) \mapsto (\rho \sin(u+\eta), \rho \sin u, \rho \sin \eta) \in \mathbb{C}^3 $ surjective?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

**Where the map comes from**

I was reading on [*The six-vertex model, $R$-matrices, and quantum groups*](http://webpages.math.luc.edu/%7Eptingley/oldseminars/QuantumGroupsSpring2011/lecture6b.pdf), where computing the eigenvalues of a transfer matrix is talked about. It is mentioned that Bethe ansatz gives the following formula for some eigenvalues: $$\Lambda = a^NL(z_1)\cdots L(z_n) + b^N M(z_1) \cdots M(z_n)  $$
where $$L(z)= \frac{ab+ (c^2-b^2)z }{a^2 - abz},  M(z)=\frac{a^2-c^2-abz}{ab-b^2z}$$
Here $a, b, c$ are complex parameters representing the weights of the vertices, and $z_1, \dots, z_n$ are complex numbers satisfying some equations.

To find restrictions imposed on $z_1 \dots, z_n$, a change of variables is introduced: $$(a,b,c,z) = ( \rho \sin(u+ \eta), \rho \sin u, \rho \sin \eta, \frac{\sin v}{\sin(u+\eta)} )$$
Then we have $$L(z) = \frac{\sin(v-u+\eta)}{\sin(v-u) }, M(z)=\frac{\sin(v-u-\eta)}{\sin(v-u)}$$

---

**Question**

How do we know that the parametrization $\mathbb{C}^3 \ni (\rho, u, \eta) \mapsto (\rho \sin(u+\eta), \rho \sin u, \rho \sin \eta) \in \mathbb{C}^3 $ is surjective?

**Attempt**

I'm trying to investigate the map $h \colon(u, \eta) \mapsto (\frac{\sin u}{\sin(u+\eta)}, \frac{\sin \eta}{\sin(u+\eta)})=(\frac{b}{a}, \frac{c}{a})$. I feel like I should do direct computation or find 'left inverse' of $h$, but there is no progress so far.

I also know that $\mathbb{R
}^3 \ni (\rho, u, \eta) \mapsto (\rho \sin(u+\eta), \rho \sin u, \rho \sin \eta) \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ cannot be surjective, since $\lvert \rho \sin(u + \eta) \rvert \leq  \lvert \rho \sin u \cos \eta \rvert + \lvert \rho \sin \eta \cos u \rvert \leq  \lvert \rho \sin u  \rvert + \lvert \rho \sin \eta  \rvert$. In complex case, this argument fails because the cosine function is unbounded. It seems surjectivity of cosine might be helpful, but I don't know how to apply this.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: This question seems complex, no $\rho, u, \eta$ intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(\frac{\sin(u+v)}{\sin u},\frac{\sin(u+v)}{\sin v}) = (\frac{a}{b}, \frac{a}{c})$, then $\frac{\sin v}{\sin u} = \frac{c}{b}$ and $\frac{\sin(u+v)}{\sin u} = \cos v+\frac{\sin v}{\sin u}\cos u = \cos v + \frac{c}{b}\cos u = \frac{a}{b}$. Square the former to get $\frac{1-\cos^2v}{1-\cos^2 u} = (\frac{c}{b})^2 := \alpha^2$, write $\beta := \frac{a}{b}$, and write $x = \cos u$ and $y = \cos v$. You have then two equations
$$
\array{
y+\alpha x = \beta \\
\alpha^2 x^2-y^2 = \alpha^2-1.
}
$$
Solve $y = \beta - \alpha x$, replace in the second and you get a linear equation in $x$ which you can solve, and then, as you said, use the surjectivity of the cosine.

If $b = 0$ or $c = 0$ I don't know what to do. If $b = 0$ then $u = 0$ or $\pi$, then $\rho(\sin(u+v),\sin v) = \rho \sin v(1, 1)$ or $\rho \sin v(-1, 1)$. Furthermore, if $a = 0$ then $\beta = 0$ and necessarily $\alpha^2 = 1$. It doesn't look quite surjective.